# Riak returns an error "Reading large object of size ..." when a mapreduce

Tags: riak

When I try to run the query mapreduce, Riak returns an error [preflist_exhausted]. In console.log a warning:

```
 riak_kv_vnode:do_get_object:1300 Reading large object of size 8360185.
```

I stored in Riak large objects (up to 20 MB). Is there a setting that will perform mapreduce on objects of this size?

My mapreduce:

```
{
"inputs":"myclients",
"query":
    [{
        "map":
               {
                    "language":"javascript",
                    "source":"function(riakObject){ return [1]; }"
               }

    },{
        "reduce":{
            "language":"javascript",
            "source":"function(values,arg){ return [values.reduce(function(acc,item){ return acc + item;},0)] ;}"
        }
     }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Riak doesn't perform well with objects larger than a couple of megabytes.  The map phase will read each object from the backend and pass it to the map function, with any non-trivial number of keys at 20Mb each, that is unlikely to ever complete before timing out.  It is possible that the fold that is employed to read the data for the map phase may cause the vnode to become overloaded, which would make it appear offline, leading to the `preflist_exhausted` message.

The `Reading large object` message is an informational message to let you know an object larger than the configured threshold has been read.  This is to alert you to objects of a size that is potentially performance-impacting.

If you must store values of that size, you should consider breaking them into chunks and storing each chunk in a separate key.  Possibly have a bucket that contains a key that represent the overall value and contains a list of block key/values that would need to be retrieved to reassemble the object.

If the values are file oriented, consider using Riak CS, which handles breaking large objects into 1Mb chunks for storage.

Comment: I need to get out of Riak completely finished object by key. I know that the size values ​​in Riak limited to 64 MB. So I chose Riak storage. And he copes with access to the object by key. Unfortunately, even a simple operation to receive a number of keys, it is impossible to perform for large objects.

Comment: In that case, consider using Riak CS, it manages breaking large objects into 1Mb blocks and storing them in Riak so the client only has deal with the complete object